# Is initialization of objects Thread Safe in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, object, initialization

I've written similar code to this in one of my applications but I'm not sure whether it is thread safe.

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    public void setObject(MyObject o) {
        myObject = o;
    }

    public MyObject getObject() {
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

The `setObject()` and `getObject()` methods will be called by different threads. The `getObject()` method is going to be called by a thread that keeps drawing on a Canvas. For optimum FPS and smooth motion, I don't want that thread to be kept waiting for a synchronization lock. Hence, I want to avoid using synchronization unless it is really necessary. So is it really necessary here? Or is there any other better way to solve this problem?

And by the way, it doesn't matter if the thread receives an older copy of the object.

Comment: "I want to avoid using synchronization unless it is really necessary" - did you evaluate synchronization overhead? You redraw canvas, say, 30 times per second, so once in 33 milliseconds you call getObject(). Synchronization (just lock, without wait()) takes less than a microsecond.

Comment: Yes thank you for noting that. I didn't actually evaluate how much time will be compromised. But I'm going to use `volatile` instead of synchronization as that will be enough in this case seeing all the other replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the status of your current version, it is definitely *not thread-safe* because concurrent access of `myObject` will establish a data race.

You didn't specify this, but if `MyObject` is not thread-safe itsef, then your program will not be thread-safe, regardless of what you do to the code you have shown.

> it doesn't matter if the thread receives an older copy of the object.

The Java Memory Model allows much worse things than that to happen to objects accessed via a data race:

- a thread may receive always the same object (the first one it happened to read);
- a thread may observe the object with only some of the reachable values initialized (a *torn* object).

> For optimum FPS and smooth motion, I don't want that thread to be kept waiting for a synchronization lock.

Have you spent any effort to actually measure how much time your threads are waiting for the lock? My guess: you didn't because that time is so short as to be undetectable.

However, your case doesn't even call for locks: just making your instance variable `volatile` will be enough to guarantee safe sharing of the object between threads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will just make the variable volatile as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not thread safe - this could happen:

- a thread may not see the latest version of `myObject` when calling `getObject` (which you can live with apparently)
- a thread may **never** see **any** updates made to `myObject` by other threads when calling `getObject`
- a thread may see an updated reference to a `MyObject` that is in a inconsistent state (partially constructed for example)

The easiest way to solve these issues is to mark `myObject` volatile.

Comment: How would a thread ever see `myObject` has a partially constructed instance? The assignment is done *after* the object is instantiated, and the assignment itself is atomic, is it not?

Comment: @dcastro nop - imagine a thread does: `MyObject o = new MyObject(); myClass.setObject(o);` the first statement includes: allocating memory, assigning a reference to `o`, constructing the object. These 3 operations and the following statement can in theory *appear* in a different order when seen from another thread, e.g. `setObject` being called before the object is constructed. Unless you introduce a proper happens-before relationship between the two threads that is.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. So a release-fence would be needed before publishing the reference. I wasn't aware the JMM allowed such reordering.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have a number of complications here:

1. myObject needs to be volatile. (Otherwise other threads may NEVER see changes).
2. The initial value of myObject will be fully constructed before MyClass is accessed so that is safe in this case, however in general you need to be careful about combining construction of objects and multi threading.

Comment: `The initial value of myObject will be fully constructed before MyClass is accessed`---this isn't true if `myObject` is not final. It will *become* true, though, if the plans for a revised Java Memory Model in Java 9 pan out.

Comment: 2. Wrong. You cannot call getObject when instance is not created yet.

Comment: If an instance of MyClass is published through a data race `myObject` may be seen in a partially constructed state.

Comment: +1 Without `volatile` the JIT can *inline* a value which means the field is never read again.

Comment: Yes, that's a datarace on MyClass - not a datarace on myObject though.

Comment: Non final and non volatile fields not guaranteed to be visible to other threads at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is thread-safe under the said conditions, so long as you mark `myObject` as `volatile`. You will always get a correct `MyObject` instance from `getObject()`.

Comment: See all the other answers. It's not safe due to lack of volatile.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the shared variable `volatile`, to let a thread know that other threads/processes/etc may change its value.

Beside that, there's no *concurrency* issue in your code.

The second line, which creates an instance of `MyObject` when an instance of `MyClass` is created, is perfectly fine. No one will have access to the shared variable *until* the instance of `MyObject` is fully constructed (unless you *leak* the shared variable from within the constructor).

The `setObject` method is also fine - all it does is assign an object to the shared variable `myObject`. And since assignments are atomic, there's nothing to worry about.